# Madal Popup MEAN Stack/Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, popup, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, mean-stack

I'm using MEAN Stack angular version 1.3.10 and trying trying to create a pop out modal.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So I have created a test button to test my popup.

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="testPopup()">Test</a>
```

This button then will go to a controller that trigger testPopup function.

```js
$scope.animationsEnabled = true;
        $scope.testPopup = function() {
            var x = $modal.open({
                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'popupEdit.html',
                controller: 'popupCtrl'
            });
        };
```

so the html for the popup is

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <h4>{{test}}</h4>
    <button ng-click="testPopout()">Test</button>
</div>
```

and this html will run this another controller which

```js
app.controller('popupCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$state',
    '$modalInstance',
    function($scope, $state, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.test = "Welcome!";
        $scope.testPopout = function() {
            console.log("popup entered!");
            $scope.test = "Testing Popup!";
            $state.go('/');
        };

        $scope.close = function() {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };
    }
]);
```

In case if this is related, my app has these dependencies

```js
var app = angular.module('displayPage', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

So back to my problem, the popup doesn't shown. Instead it displays this error:
"angular.js:11598 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/ng/areq?
    at angular.js:38
    at resolveSuccess (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js:2171)

Comment: Is this your full error message?

Comment: @PhillipPlum no it's not. part of it that I think necessary. coz I've tried to put all the errors but SO doesn't allow me to post it. So I have to delete some of the errors. But all those errors does not come from my code.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot from the full error message? I think, the part of the error you posted is not the real problem.

Comment: @phillip plum it's okay. I have figure it out. Problem is solve